# updating database from gridview using an alertbox popup in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-gridview

I'm developing an Customer details for a shop using Grid view in android. I get the details of my Customers using my Database. I need to update the Stocks handled by the Customer using an alert box for entering the Stock Quantity while performing the Transaction..

customergrid.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/tab1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <GridView
          android:id="@+id/grid"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="357dp"
          android:numColumns="1"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/cancel"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="cancel" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

And, for each Row I have used a customized Xml file..

customerrow.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
     <TableRow>
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="50px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/row_ID"
             android:padding="5px"
             android:layout_weight="1" />
         <TextView 
             android:layout_width="50px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/key_ID"
             android:padding="5px"
             android:layout_weight="1" />
         <TextView 
             android:layout_width="50px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/key_Description"
             android:padding="5px"
             android:layout_weight="1" />
     </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

And I have Used customergrid.xml on the Oncreate() method and use customerrow.xml in the Grid creation like as the following code..

```
 public void FillGrid() {
     DatabaseHelper sqdb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
     sqdb.openDataBase();
     Cursor cursor;
     GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grvData);
     cursor = sqdb.getGridData();
     sqdb.close();
     if (cursor != null) {
         startManagingCursor(cursor); 
         SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
             R.layout.customerrow, cursor, new String[] { CustomerActivity.KEY_ROW_ID,
             CustomerActivity.KEY_ID, CustomerActivity.KEY_DESCRIPTION }, new int[] {
             R.id.txtGrv_id, R.id.txtGrvid, R.id.txtGrvDescription } );
         adapter.setViewResource(R.layout.gridlayout);
         grid.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

And finally I used alert box with an editbox for getting the input of Customer's Stock Quantity. I use this for that task..

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new  OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b=new AlertDialog.Builder(MarkSheet.this);
        b.setTitle("Employee Details");
        LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(MarkSheet.this);
        View v=li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_get);
        b.setView(v);
        final TextView txtName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        final EditText Quantity=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.Quantity);

        // Here I need to update the table while clicking the positive button, if I click negative button I need to cancel the Dialog box..

     }
 });
```

Anybody help me for Complete this task..

Answer (score 0):

you can find the code for updating the database table [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html)  and the concept of alert box [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/alert-box-code.html)

You need to call the update method of the sqlite from the code where you clicked the button "ok".

Comment: In my Dialog box, I have to perform two Editbox for entering the value of Product Name and Quantity of the Product. And Each Editbox will keep respective TextView. In the Example i could get only one Editbox. How could i get the Dialog box with 2 Textview, 2 Edittext and 2 Buttons(Submit & Cancel)..